# How to update a portlet in all opened pages

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, liferay

I have portlet as a navigation bar in my web application,it contains some elements with count on them which can be changed from different pages.I want to update the navigation bar for all opened pages and also for users using the application.

Currently for this i am using prime-faces poll to update my navigation bar elements after specific time,but this is resulting in inconsistent representation of navigation bar (on multiple pages and for multiple users).I want something which can immediately update the navigation bar.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin: Portlets, or rather portlet based solutuions still have their advantage **IF** used correctly (right way, right environment etc). They can solve lots of basic things that you do not need to develop yourselves...

Comment: How is polling causing inconsistency?Could you please provide some scenarios and cases where it happens!

Comment: did you also explore on the long polling mechanism?

Comment: for example i have a poll of 2 minutes and i opened two pages with nav bar with an interval of 1 minute both pages will show different data after 1 minute

Comment: It seems like it would be more appropriate to use [PrimeFaces Push with `p:socket`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) for this. Check out all the examples to see if one is similar to your use case: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/. As long as you are not [using `p:socket` for inter-portlet communication](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/337), I *think* `p:socket` will work fine in portlets.

Comment: prime faces push services are not working, even in their demo they are not working

Comment: [I opened an issue for the PrimeFaces Showcase.](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/issues/25) Please vote for it. You should try temporarily using http in your environment to see if PrimeFaces push will work for your issue (I think the issue only occurs with https).

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in Liferay 7 which causes PrimeFaces push to fail: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-72753.

Comment: Here is an example portlet which uses PrimeFaces 6.1 Push in Liferay 6.2: https://github.com/stiemannkj1/liferay-faces-bridge-impl/tree/develop-primepush-cdi-counter-portlet-demo-FACES-1387-4.x/demo/primepush-cdi-counter-portlet